# OneToMany & ManyToOne in Hibernate Mapping

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, model, annotations

```
public class ClassYear {
    private Set<Examination> examination = new HashSet<Examination>();

    @Id
    @Column(name = "class_id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @DocumentId
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL},fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="class_id")
    public Set<Examination> getExamination() {
        return examination;
    }

    public void setExamination(Set<Examination> examination) {
        this.examination = examination;
    }
}

public class Examination {
    private ClassYear classYear;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL},fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="class_id")
    public ClassYear getClassYear() {
        return classYear;
    }

    public void setClassYear(ClassYear classYear) {
        this.classYear = classYear;
    }
}
```

So here, Examination table refers the class_id column of ClassYear table. Now I need the class_id column to be used on few other tables. How should I do it..? It's One to many relationship concept but I need that class_id to be used on many tables (say like HomeWork table). I searched the Internet and found explanations for one to many & many to one concepts, but I can't find exactly how to do it for multiple tables with a particular column in a table as One to Many relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Examination` entity owns the relationship, so you should map the examinations in `ClassYear` entity (which is the non-owning side of the relationship) using `mappedBy` like this (without join column):

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="classYear", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
public Set<Examination> getExamination() {
    return examination;
}
```

I removed the `EAGER` fetch type in this example (the default for `@OneToMany` is `LAZY`). I don't know your use case but always eagerly fetching mapped collections like this is not the best idea.

If you need to reference `ClassYear` in other entities like `HomeWork`, do it the same way. The `HomeWork` entity will have `@ManyToOne` mapping to `ClassYear` and will be the owning side of the relationship (just like in `Examination`) and all the homeworks for the `ClassYear` can be mapped using `mappedBy` in the `ClassYear` entity.

Also one small detail:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL},fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
```

`@ManyToOne` has the `EAGER` fetch type as default, so you don't have to specify it manually.